# compare columns from different files and print those that DO NOT match

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files, file1 and file2. I want to compare several columns - $1,$2 ,$3 and $4 of file1 with several columns $1,$2, $3 and $4 of file2 and print those rows of file2 that do not match any row in file1.

E.g.

file1

```
aaa bbb ccc 1 2 3
aaa ccc eee 4 5 6
fff sss sss 7 8 9
```

file2

```
aaa bbb ccc 1 f a
mmm nnn ooo 1 d e
aaa ccc eee 4 a b
ppp qqq rrr 4 e a
sss ttt uuu 7 m n
fff sss sss 7 5 6
```

I want to have as output:

```
mmm nnn ooo 1 d e
ppp qqq rrr 4 e a
sss ttt uuu 7 m n
```

I have seen questions asked here for finding those that do match and printing them, but not viceversa,those that DO NOT match.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following script:

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4} NR==FNR{a[k]; next} !(k in a)' file1 file2
```

`k` is the concatenated value of the columns `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, delimited by `FS` (see [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165608/compare-columns-from-different-files-and-print-those-that-do-not-match/42165712?noredirect=1#comment71502983_42165712)), and will be used as a key in a search array `a` later. `NR==FNR` is `true` while reading `file1`. I'm creating the array `a` indexed by `k` while reading `file1`.

For the remaining lines of input I check with `!(k in a)` if the index does not exists in `a`. If that evaluates to `true` `awk` will print that line.

Comment: Invert the condition, katarina wants "not in a"

Comment: concatenating fields this way may end up with wrong results, e.g `aaa bb` and `a aabb` wll be treated the same.  Better use `,` between the fields or at least `FS`

Comment: Good point. Thank you both! I've used Ed's suggestion, it is perfect!

Comment: how would it be if I would have different columns in different files? 
For example - comparing $1 and $2 from file1 with $4 and $7 from file2

Comment: Then you would need two variables. `k1` and `k2`

Comment: Yes that worked as well, thanks.
And what is the actual meaning of "a[k]" and "k in a"? 
I see that "k" is the concatenated value of those columns as you've written, but is it the value of those columns for one specific line that's determined by "a"?

Comment: `a` is an associative array, or call it a hash table. `k in a` checks if the hash `k` exists.

Answer (score 3):

here is another approach if the files are sorted and you know the used char set.

```
$ function f(){ sed 's/ /~/g;s/~/ /4g' $1; }; join -v2 <(f file1) <(f file2) | 
  sed 's/~/ /g'

mmm nnn ooo 1 d e
aaa ccc eee 4 a b
ppp qqq rrr 4 e a
sss ttt uuu 7 m n
fff sss sss 7 5 6
```

create a key field by concatenating first four fields (with a `~` char, but any unused char can be used), use `join` to find the unmatched entries from file2 and partition the synthetic key field back.

However, the best way is to use `awk` solution with a slight fix

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3,$4]; next} !(($1,$2,$3,$4) in a)' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

No doubt that the `awk` solution from @hek2mgl is better than this one, but for information this is also possible using `uniq`, `sort`, and `rev`:

```
rev file1 file2 | sort -k3 | uniq -u -f2 | rev
```

`rev` is reverting both files from right to left.

`sort -k3` is sorting lines skipping the 2 first column.

`uniq -u -f2` prints only lines that are unique (skipping the 2 first while comparing).

At last the `rev` is reverting back the lines.

This solution sorts the lines of both files. That might be desired or not.